# Introspect a Scala class for traits?

Tags: scala

Is there an introspection api somewhere in Scala to find the traits a class is implementing ?

For Scala 2.9.2 that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trait in Scala translate to interfaces in Java, so you can use Java's reflection library to find out which traits are implemented. Here is an example:

```
trait Foo
class Bar extends Foo 

val b = new Bar
b.getClass.getInterfaces.foreach(println)
```

This prints:

```
interface Foo
interface scala.ScalaObject
```

Comment: That's right - but I only get ScalaObject instances from Class.getInterfaces. getDeclaredMethods on that yields nothing. No clue where to get from there...

Comment: @JanGoyvaerts You must be doing something wrong. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the example ! :-) I'll try that asap.

Comment: You were right. I was probably checking the wrong piece of code. BUT ... how to proceed from there ? I want to know whether methods in the trait has been annotated with a specific annotation. :-)

Comment: That's not what your question was about, you should ask another one if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Fair enough. I was going to mark this as answered anyway. :-)

Comment: There you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101235/introspect-scala-traits.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the example Kim Stebel used does not work if the trait is implemented by a superclass. Here is a more general form:

```
  def implementsInterface(target: Class[_], someInterface: Class[_]): Boolean = {
    val i = target.getInterfaces
    i.foreach((c: Class[_]) => if (c == someInterface) return true)

    val s = target.getSuperclass

    if (s == null) false
    else implementsInterface(s, someInterface)
  }
```