# Introspect Scala traits

Tags: scala, introspection

Consider the example

```
class FooListener extends Listener {
  @Listen
  def runMeToo = {
    ...
  }
}

trait Listener {

  @Listen
  def runMe = {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm writing introspection code to find all methods of a given class (ie **FooListener**) annotated with a certain annotation (ie **@Listen**). They'll be invoked under certain circumstances. So I need all their **java.lang.Method** instances.

It's easy to find those methods in the FooListener class. Easy also to find those of the super classes.

The question is how to find those inherited from the traits ? And the traits of the traits ? Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods inherited from a trait are just copied into the class. So you can find them by just listing the methods of the class.

```
val ms = classOf[FooListener].getMethods()
```

And then print them with their annotations.

```
ms.foreach(m => m.getDeclaredAnnotations().foreach(a => println(m + " " + a)))
```

In my case (annotated with `Test`), this prints

```
public void util.FooListener.runMe() @org.junit.Test(expected=class org.junit.Test$None, timeout=0)
public void util.FooListener.runMeToo() @org.junit.Test(expected=class org.junit.Test$None, timeout=0)
```

Comment: This works ! (sorry for being this late) However, any clue about private methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Since traits are translated to interfaces in Java, the following code snippet should work:

```
val methods = classOf[FooListener].getInterfaces flatMap {intf =>
    intf.getMethods filter {_.getAnnotation(classOf[Listen]) != null}
}
```